# approximate a product of multiple variables

Tags: convex-optimization, approximation, maxima-minima

I am trying to deal with an optimization problem with the following formulation

$$\mbox{minimize}_{x} \quad \max\limits_f \{\sum_{i=1}^N C_{i,f} \prod_{j=1}^i (1-x_{j,f})  \}, 0\leq x \leq 1$$

I don't want to solve this problem using geometric programming, since $e^x + e^{1-x}=1$ is nonconvex. Thus, my idea is to approximate the max function and the product $\prod_{j=1}^i (1-x_{j,f})$. Is there any way I can do that to approximate the original objective function to a convex function with a bounded optimality guarantee?

Comment: $C_{i,f}$ is what? Binomial coefficients?

Comment: @Jam Yes, $C_{i,f}$ are constants

Comment: I do not see where the "="  in "since .. is nonconvex" comes from. If you substitute $y_{jf}=\log(1-x_{jf})$, it becomes convex, right?